# Instantiate a generic Number class in Java

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to create an Array-like object that can store `Number` types.
I want to initialize each value in `Object[] array` to `0`.
If I knew that the `NegativeArray` was storing `Integer`s,
then I could do `new Integer(0)`.
Unfortunately, when dealing with the generic type `E`,
I don't know how to create a new `Number` with value `0`.

This is my current implementation:

```
package com.gly.sfs.util;

public class NegativeArray <E extends Number> {

    private int firstIndex;
    private int lastIndex;
    private Object[] array;

    public NegativeArray(int firstIndex, int lastIndex) {
        this.firstIndex = firstIndex;
        this.lastIndex = lastIndex;

        boolean isValid = lastIndex > firstIndex; 
        if (!isValid) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "lastIndex > firstIndex violated!");
        }

        array = new Object[size()];
    }

    public void set(int index, E e) {
        checkIndexValidity(index);
        array[getIndex(index)] = e;
    }

    public E get(int index) {
        checkIndexValidity(index);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        E e = (E) array[getIndex(index)];
        return e;
    }

    public int size() {
        return lastIndex - firstIndex;
    }

    private int getIndex(int index) {
        return index - firstIndex;
    }

    private void checkIndexValidity(int index) {
        boolean isValid = (index >= firstIndex) & 
                (index < lastIndex);
        if (!isValid) {
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note, you probably want `E[] array`, not `Object[] array`.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers: No, the way he is doing it is safer.

Comment: Why do you want to initialize each member of array to 0?

Comment: In Java, when a new `int[]` array is created it is initialized to zero. I want my `NegativeArray` class to have the same behavior. Otherwise, `get(index)` will return `null` rather than zero.

Answer (score 0):

You need more than `E`: you either need a separate contract that says `E` has a `getZero()` method, or you need to accept a `getZero` method separately.

In Java 8 you can accept a `Supplier< E >` in addition to the other arguments in your constructor, and you can have a few stock `Supplier`s around for the common `Number` subclasses.

In Java 7 and earlier, you can manually define the `ZeroSupplier<E>` interface.